# Can't make changes to java classes with Hibernate reverse engineering

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, netbeans, hibernate-mapping

I'm working with Hibernate for the first time for a school project where we are building a Yelp-like app for food trucks. However, because I created my database schema first, I'm using Hibernate's reverse engineering feature to generate Java classes. However, I cannot get Hibernate to generate the Java classes the way I want them. Here's my hibernate.reveng.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Reverse Engineering DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
  <schema-selection match-catalog="FoodTrucks"/>
  <table-filter match-name="item"/>
  <table-filter match-name="tags"/>
  <table-filter match-name="truck"/>
  <table-filter match-name="menu"/>
  <table-filter match-name="tag_item_map" exclude="true"/>
  <table-filter match-name="user"/>
  <table-filter match-name="item_review"/>
  <table-filter match-name="truck_review"/>
  <table name="item">
       <column name="menu_id" exclude="true"></column>
       <foreign-key constraint-name="item_review_ibfk_2">
          <many-to-one property="items"></many-to-one>
       </foreign-key>
       <foreign-key constraint-name="tag_item_map_ibfk_1">
          <set property="tags"></set>
      </foreign-key>
  </table>
  <table name="menu">
      <column name="truck_id" exclude="true"></column>
      <foreign-key constraint-name="item_ibfk_1">
          <many-to-one property="items"></many-to-one>
      </foreign-key>
  </table>
  <table name="tags">
      <foreign-key constraint-name="tag_item_map_ibfk_2">
          <many-to-one property="items"></many-to-one>
      </foreign-key>
  </table>
  <table name="truck">
      <foreign-key constraint-name="menu_ibfk_1">
          <many-to-one property="menus"></many-to-one>
      </foreign-key>
      <foreign-key constraint-name="truck_review_ibfk_2">
          <many-to-one property="reviews"></many-to-one>
      </foreign-key>
  </table>
  <table name="user">
      <column name="pass_word" exclude="true"></column>
       <foreign-key constraint-name="item_review_ibfk_1">
          <many-to-one property="itemReviews"></many-to-one>
      </foreign-key>
      <foreign-key constraint-name="truck_review_ibfk_1">
          <many-to-one property="truckReviews"></many-to-one>
      </foreign-key>
  </table>
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

However, the only thing I was able to get it do properly was exclude the tag to item table. For example, here's the generated Item class, sans getters and setters.

```
public class Item  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private Integer id;
     private Menu items;
     private String itemName;
     private double price;
     private Set itemReviews = new HashSet(0);

    public Item() {
    }


    public Item(String itemName, double price) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
        this.price = price;
    }
    public Item(Menu items, String itemName, double price, Set itemReviews) {
       this.items = items;
       this.itemName = itemName;
       this.price = price;
       this.itemReviews = itemReviews;
    }

// getters and setters down here
}
```

I know I'm doing something either wrong or improperly but I have no idea what. In addition, when I try to generate code after the initial generation, I get this error message "Hibernate configuration fails with message: resource: model/Item.hbm.xml not found see message.log for exception details." despite the fact that Item.hbm.xml is there.

Answer (score 0):

You weren´t specific on how you want your Java classes?

Follow this tutorial to the letter - it will help to understand the process/steps https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/hibernate-java-se.ht
ml